# SparkContext cannot be initialized in 'yarn-client' mode called from Scala-IDE

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have installed Cloudera VM (Single node) and inside this VM i have Spark running on top of Yarn. I would like to use Eclipse IDE (with scala plugin) for testing/learning with Spark.

If i instantiate SparkContext as following, everything works as i expected

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterPopularTags").setMaster("local[2]")
```

However, if i want now to connect to local server by changing the master to 'yarn-client' then it does not work:

```
val master = "yarn-client"
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterPopularTags").setMaster(master)
```

Specifically im getting following errors:

Error details displayed in the Eclipse console:

[image]

Error details from the NodeManager logs:

[image]

Here are the things i have tried so far:
**1. Dependencies**
I added all the dependencies through Maven repository
Cloudera version is 5.5 and corresponding Hadoop version is 2.6.0 and Spark version is 1.5.0.

**2. Configurations**
I added 3 path variables into Eclipse classpath:

- SPARK_CONF_DIR=/etc/spark/conf/
- HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop/
- YARN_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/

Can anybody clarify me what is the problem here and ways to solve it?

Comment: Please check for the error details from the Yarn's JobHistory Server
http://i.stack.imgur.com/aI4SD.png

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it! I still don't understand what the exact problems is but i created a folder with my username in hadoop , i.e. /user/*myusername* directory and it worked. Anyway now i switched to Hortonworks distribution and i found it much more smoother to get started with than the Cloudera distribution.